# Update column value property in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a table in sql server 2008 at creating time i did not set a NOT NULL and PRIMARY KEY property i want to update table with NOT NULL and PRIMARY KEY property how to do it

Comment: Look for `ALTER TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Open up Sql Management Studio, login, unfold the database and `Tables` branch, right-click the table to be modified, select "Design" make modifications as needed. Actually, setting the column to primary key (by right-clicking and selecting from the popup menu), `NOT NULL` will automatically be set, too.

Answer (score 0):

Make column not nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTable] 
ALTER COLUMN [YourColumn] INT NOT NULL; -- CHANGE DATA TYPE AS REQUIRED
```

Make column primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTable] 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable__YourColumn PRIMARY KEY (YourColumn);
```